# I have uploaded my attachments using following code.It's work fine. It may be images,word files etc...Is anyone develop any java code to display data?

Tags: image, upload, ejb-3.0, servlet-3.0, getimagedata

This is my upload attachment code.

```
            if (!item.isFormField())
            {
                String fileName = item.getName();
                String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
                if (!path.exists()) {
                 boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                }
                File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                item.write(uploadedFile);
            }
```

How sholud i display my image and files using java code?